# Auto-populating a Formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

***Requirement :***
Need to auto populate the formula only for the cells which has the data.

***Solution :***
Created formula via VB script :

```
Sub Insert_Formula()

    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Range("DJ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("DK2:DK" & Lastrow).Formula = "=TIMEVALUE(DH2)"

End Sub
```

***Issue:***

*Now the formula is being applied to first row also. How can I exclude the header row ?
And result of the first row is being populated in remaining rows (though the formula is relevantly populated).

Or is there any other way to auto populate the formulas dynamically based on the data available ?*

Comment: That suggests that the value of `Lastrow` is 1.

Comment: Thanks @SJR . I got it. It resolved.  Now the formula is populating  for all the rows which has data in the relative column. But the data is wrong- Though the formula is respective to column (formula populated in the remaining rows) , the value in first row is been published throughout. Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by SJR, the value of `Lastrow` is 1. In order to fix it, simply write:

```
If Lastrow = 1 Then Lastrow = 2
Range("DK2:DK" & Lastrow).Formula = "=TIMEVALUE(DH2)"
```

Comment: Thanks @Vityata . I got it. It resolved.  Now the formula is populating  for all the rows which has data in the relative column. But the data is wrong- Though the formula is respective to column (formula populated in the remaining rows) , the value in first row is been published throughout. Any clue ?

Comment: @LohithGowda I experienced that issue recently. My solution involved turning on the automatic calculations again as it had somehow gotten changed to manual. Although, when I pressed the save icon while the calculation was manual, the cells were updated to the correct value right before the workbook saved.

Comment: @LohithGowda Also, if Vityata's answer solved the initial question, you should consider marking it as the accepted answer.